# Reading a File by passing a parameter to function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a file be by passing parameter to a function in R. The same syntax works outside the function but not in it.

```
> corr <- function(directory){
z <- sprintf("C:\\Users\\rajat\\Documents\\education\\Coursera\\Computing for Data  Analysis\\%s\\001.csv",directory)
print(z)
data2<-read.csv(z)
}
corr(directory="specdata")
[1] "C:\\Users\\rajat\\Documents\\education\\Coursera\\Computing for Data Analysis\\specdata\\001.csv"
> data2
> Error: object 'data2' not found
```

The one without using function gives proper result.

```
  > directory="specdata"
  > z <- sprintf("C:\\Users\\rajat\\Documents\\education\\Coursera\\Computing for Data Analysis\\%s\\001.csv",directory)
  > print(z)
  [1] "C:\\Users\\rajat\\Documents\\education\\Coursera\\Computing for Data Analysis\\specdata\\001.csv"
  > data1<-read.csv(z)

  > str(data1)
  'data.frame': 1461 obs. of  4 variables:
  $ Date   : Factor w/ 1461 levels "2003-01-01","2003-01-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data2` just exists in the environment of your `corr` function. To make it globally available, do `data2<<-read.csv(z)`. Then it will be found outside the function. More info: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html

**Disclaimer**: A cleaner way would be to return the data from the function like this:

```
corr <- function(directory) {
  z <- sprintf("C:\\Users\\rajat\\Documents\\education\\Coursera\\Computing for Data  Analysis\\%s\\001.csv",directory)
  print(z)
  return(read.csv(z))
}

data2 <- corr(directory="specdata")
data2
```

See @thelatemail's comment below.

Comment: That's not good advice. You should avoid `<<-` when at all possible. The `corr` function should instead return `read.csv(z)` which can then be assigned to `data2` using the standard `<-`

Comment: @thelatemail no, prly not. It was the easiest. :)

Comment: Given that it seems Rajat is doing a Coursera course on R, it is probably wise to at least put a disclaimer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!! :) I did it the following way..
        read.csv(z)
        return()
As I don't want whole dataset to be printed in my console, which I believe the following command does. 
         return(read.csv(z))